# How do I stack a child on top of another parent?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list of figure tags each with a pop out figcaption.
In each figure is a clickable div that transitions the figcaption to be visible.  I have many figure tags on the page and when the figcaption is visable, it only stacks over the figure it belongs to but not others.  Is there a way to stack the visible figcaption on top of all parents?

I set up a fiddle with the code to try to get it to work and I finally did but when I transferred it over to my site, it still didn't work.  I have IE11 and Chrome set up and it doesn't work on either.

http://jsfiddle.net/carlsc3/nxocs121/

HTML:

```
<div class=TransInfo>
    <figure class=FRM>
        <div class="CB"></div>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/">Link 1</a>
        <figcaption>Description of the Link that is in the figure a href blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah thingie</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class=FRM>
        <div class="CB"></div>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/">Link 2</a>
        <figcaption>Description of the Link that is in the figure a href blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah thingie</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.TransInfo {
    background-color: #E4F1FB;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 300px;
}
figure {
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #B8B8B8;
    overflow: visible;
}
figure a {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #4E5052;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
}
figcaption {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: -15px 0 0 15px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: red;
    border: 2px solid black;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #B8B8B8;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: central;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}
.CBclick {
    -webkit-animation: fighov 0.3s ease-out 0s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation: fighov 0.3s ease-out 0s;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation: fighov 0.3s ease-out 0s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes fighov {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        backface-visibility: visible;
        z-index: 10;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fighov {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
        z-index: 10;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fighov {
    0% {div.TransInfo {
    background-color: #E4F1FB;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 300px;
}
figure {
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #B8B8B8;
    overflow: visible;
}
figure a {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #4E5052;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
}
figcaption {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: -15px 0 0 15px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: red;
    border: 2px solid black;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #B8B8B8;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: central;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}
.CBclick {
    -webkit-animation: fighov 0.3s ease-out 0s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation: fighov 0.3s ease-out 0s;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation: fighov 0.3s ease-out 0s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes fighov {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        backface-visibility: visible;
        z-index: 10;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fighov {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
        z-index: 10;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fighov {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-backface-visibility: visible;
        z-index: 10;
    }
}
.CB {
    cursor: help;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 15px solid #4E5052;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    z-index: 1;
}
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-backface-visibility: visible;
        z-index: 10;
    }
}
.CB {
    cursor: help;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 15px solid #4E5052;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
$("div.CB").click(function () {
    var thisTime = this;
    $(thisTime).siblings('figcaption').addClass('CBclick');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(thisTime).siblings('figcaption').removeClass('CBclick');
    }, 5000);
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

.prepend() took care of the main issue I was having.

After adding the prepend statement, the figcaption would hover over any of the parents.

In order to make the figcaption hover underneath it's original figure, instead of the top left corner, I used the .offset() statement to change the position of the prepended figcaption relative to it's initial parent figure.

To make everything reset so the user can view another figcaption after viewing one, I used the clone() statement so I could remove() the figcaption and it wouldn't effect the future use without having to reload the page.

See my changed jquery below

```
$("div.CB").click(function () {                                 /* Bind click event to the top corner triangle */
    $("div.TransInfo").children('figcaption').remove();
    var thisTime = this;                                        /* 'this' keyword does not work within the setTimeout function */
    var FigPos = $(thisTime).parent('figure');                  /* Set variable to parent figure */
    var top = FigPos.offset().top;                              /* Set variable to position from top of div*/
    var left = FigPos.offset().left;                            /* Set variable to position from left of div */
    $(thisTime).siblings('figcaption').clone().prependTo("div.TransInfo");                   /* Attach the figcaption to the TransInfo div */
    $("div.TransInfo").children('figcaption').addClass('CBclick');     /* Toggle the tool tip visibility */
    $("div.TransInfo").children('figcaption').css({ "top": top + 20, "left": left - 25 }); /* Set position of figcaption to just under parent figure */
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("div.TransInfo").children('figcaption').css({ "top": "", "left": "" });
        $("div.TransInfo").children('figcaption').removeClass('CBclick');
        $("div.TransInfo").children('figcaption').remove();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `prepend()` function

Example:

```
$( ".parentClass" ).prepend( ".childClass" );
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, it was a huge help